# convert long as varchar in db into type long

Tags: c#, long-integer, varchar

I have number in database, for example 733.25 which is stored as varchar in mssql.

the datareader will read it as string object "733.25"

How can i convert it to long (int64) ?

Int64.Parse returns error

(long)Convert.ToDecimal returns "73325"

Thank you

Comment: Do you want it as an int or float ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In .NET make sure to use `InvariantCulture`.

   ```
   decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal("733.25", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   ```

   More Information: [MSDN: Using the InvariantCulture Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c5zdc6a.aspx)
2. In T-SQL you can cast that in your query.

   ```
   SELECT cast('733.25' as float)
   ```

   More Information: [MSDN: CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Both will result in 733.25.

**hope this helps**

Comment: Thank you dknaack, i will probably use the TSQL because i want the database to return data in correct format.

Answer (score 1):

### You can parse the value as below

```
double.Parse(Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are after code like this:

```
string val = "733.25";

long longVal = (long)decimal.Parse(val);

// longVal will now contain the value you want
```

You have to parse the value as a decimal before converting to long (which has the result of dropping off the decimal places).  Note that you are losing precision by doing this, which is why you need an explicit conversion.

Comment: This does not work, the string 733.25 will end up as long integer 73325000

Comment: That code works in a console app.  If you paste the code in that you are running so I can see why it's not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cast and Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) T-SQL with SQL statement.

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(decimal, strColumn1) AS bigint) From TableName
```